# Background color of roGridScreen

Tags: roku, brightscript

In Roku BrightScript, is there any way to change the background color of [roGridScreen](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roGridScreen) to a dark blue color?

There is the attribute `GridScreenBackgroundColor` in [roAppManager](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roAppManager), but that only allows settings of grayscale values. If you try a full color dark blue value there, the entire gridscreen changes color to have a strange purple hue over all content instead of setting the desired background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received the following answer at the [Roku developer forum](http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=87670#p494580):

*"Most gridscreen styles don't allow more than greyscale, but I think there may be a couple of modes that allow color. Unfortunately color in those modes sometimes produces weird color artifacts like you described and or weird green flashes. Its really designed to be greyscale. If you must have a grid with a color background, then you might want to use roScreen to create your own gridscreen."*